Google Firebase in and notIn queries do not work in Swift
I copied and pasted the code from the google snippet:
let citiesRef = db.collection("cities")

citiesRef.whereField("country", in: ["USA", "Japan"])
// [END in_filter]

// [START in_filter_with_array]
citiesRef.whereField("regions", in: [["west_coast"], ["east_coast"]])
// [END in_filter_with_array]

// [START not_in_filter]
citiesRef.whereField("country", notIn: ["USA", "Japan"])
// [END not_in_filter]

As you can see, the in the pasted code from google snippets

In the Google copy/paste code, the .whereField is in white color, not green, meaning it's not recognized code.
In my custom code at the bottom, .whereField is green.

As far as I can tell, "in" and "notIn" do not work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

That's a little odd but how do you know in and notIn do not work?
